# Can GTK themes and extensions access my personal files?

Tags: themes, security, gtk3

I would like to install third party gtk themes in my laptop running on Ubuntu 20.04. I would like to know of there's any security issues in doing so.

By security issues I meant privacy issues and problems with the proper function of my pc.

Do my personal files can be accessed by using such themes or other extensions.

Comment: With extensions possibility is there. GTK themes no issues.

Comment: GTK themes means you are keeping some folders offline in your home directory. They just sit. Extensions can run commands if configured to do so.

Comment: If you download extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org. they are tested for security. This way of installing extensions are safe.

Comment: are there themes in extensions.gnome.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Risk**

The risk is essentially not with the theme itself, but with the way the theme is installed. When installed through a `.deb` installation file or through a script you need to run, then, yes, there is a security risk like with any software that you install outside of the official software sources, or other highly trusted sources. Malicious code can be injected in any install procedure, including that of themes.

If the installation just involves placing files in the appropriate folders (e.g. `~/.local/share/themes` or `~/.themes`, then you are not running any external scripts, and security risks are very minimal (theoretically never 0, but very close to it).

**Proper functioning**

With respect to proper functioning of your PC, the usability of your computer can be affected if the theme contains errors or is flawed. This is easily circumvented by changing back to a better quality theme.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more question how can i know that the theme contains errors.

Comment: In the gnome tweaks app, it is showing that i have no gnome shell. but when i try to install it via the terminal it says that the package is already installed.